# Add class 'Show' to 'btn-group' when checkbox inside it is clicked using Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-4

I am 100% new to Vue and I can't seem to figure out how to do the below.

I have a `btn-group` which has `checkboxes` inside it as shown by the HTML below

```
<div class="col-12 col-sm-3">
    <label class="w-100 mb-0" for="orderStatusListDiv">Order status</label>
    <div id="orderStatusListDiv" class="btn-group w-100" role="group">
        <button id="orderStatusList" type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
        aria-expanded="false" style="border: 1px solid #ced4da; text-align: left">
        Order status filter
        <span class="caret" style="margin-left: 120px"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdownCheckBox">                                         
        <div id="orderStatusCheckboxDiv" class="custom-control custom-checkbox dropdownCheckBoxDiv">
            <input id="orderStatusSelectUnselectCheckbox" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" v-model="osSelectAll">
            <label id="orderStatusSelectUnselectCheckboxLabel" for="orderStatusSelectUnselectCheckbox" class="custom-control-label">
                {{ osSelectAllLabel }}
            </label>
        </div>
        <div v-for="osCheckbox in osCheckboxes" class="custom-control custom-checkbox dropdownCheckBoxDiv">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" v-model="osSelected" :value="osCheckbox.id">
            <label class="custom-control-label" style="font-weight: normal">
                {{ osCheckbox.name }}
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

**DEV Tools Generated HTML**

```
<div data-v-5de224cd="" class="dropdown-menu dropdownCheckBox show" x-placement="bottom-start" style="position: absolute; will-change: transform; top: 0px; left: 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, 34px, 0px);">
    <div data-v-5de224cd="" id="orderStatusCheckboxDiv" class="custom-control custom-checkbox dropdownCheckBoxDiv">
        <input data-v-5de224cd="" id="orderStatusSelectUnselectCheckbox" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
        <label data-v-5de224cd="" id="orderStatusSelectUnselectCheckboxLabel" for="orderStatusSelectUnselectCheckbox" class="custom-control-label">
            Unselect all
        </label>
    </div>
    <div data-v-5de224cd="" class="custom-control custom-checkbox dropdownCheckBoxDiv">
        <input data-v-5de224cd="" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="awaitingDespatch">
        <label data-v-5de224cd="" class="custom-control-label" style="font-weight: normal;">
            Awaiting - Despatch
        </label>
    </div>
    <div data-v-5de224cd="" class="custom-control custom-checkbox dropdownCheckBoxDiv">
        <input data-v-5de224cd="" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="awaitingStock">
        <label data-v-5de224cd="" class="custom-control-label" style="font-weight: normal;">
            Awaiting - Stock
        </label>
    </div>
    <div data-v-5de224cd="" class="custom-control custom-checkbox dropdownCheckBoxDiv">
        <input data-v-5de224cd="" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="cancelledPostOrder">
        <label data-v-5de224cd="" class="custom-control-label" style="font-weight: normal;">
            Cancelled - Post-order
        </label>
    </div>
    <div data-v-5de224cd="" class="custom-control custom-checkbox dropdownCheckBoxDiv">
        <input data-v-5de224cd="" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="cancelledPreOrder">
        <label data-v-5de224cd="" class="custom-control-label" style="font-weight: normal;">
            Cancelled - Pre-order
        </label>
    </div>
    <div data-v-5de224cd="" class="custom-control custom-checkbox dropdownCheckBoxDiv">
        <input data-v-5de224cd="" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="completed">
        <label data-v-5de224cd="" class="custom-control-label" style="font-weight: normal;">
            Completed
        </label>
    </div>
    <div data-v-5de224cd="" class="custom-control custom-checkbox dropdownCheckBoxDiv">
        <input data-v-5de224cd="" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="created">
        <label data-v-5de224cd="" class="custom-control-label" style="font-weight: normal;">
            Created
        </label>
    </div>
    <div data-v-5de224cd="" class="custom-control custom-checkbox dropdownCheckBoxDiv">
        <input data-v-5de224cd="" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="fullyInvoiced">
        <label data-v-5de224cd="" class="custom-control-label" style="font-weight: normal;">
            Fully invoiced
        </label>
    </div>
    <div data-v-5de224cd="" class="custom-control custom-checkbox dropdownCheckBoxDiv">
        <input data-v-5de224cd="" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="orderError">
        <label data-v-5de224cd="" class="custom-control-label" style="font-weight: normal;">
            Order error
        </label>
    </div>
    <div data-v-5de224cd="" class="custom-control custom-checkbox dropdownCheckBoxDiv">
        <input data-v-5de224cd="" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="ShippedMoreThanOne">
        <label data-v-5de224cd="" class="custom-control-label" style="font-weight: normal;">
            Shipped - More than one delivery
        </label>
    </div>
    <div data-v-5de224cd="" class="custom-control custom-checkbox dropdownCheckBoxDiv">
        <input data-v-5de224cd="" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="ShippedPart">
        <label data-v-5de224cd="" class="custom-control-label" style="font-weight: normal;">
            Shipped - Part
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

I know that when you click on the `btn-group` the `show` `class` is added to the parent, in my case:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdownCheckBox">
```

The issue I can't seem to resolve is than when I click on the below:

```
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox dropdownCheckBoxDiv">
```

it closes and I want it to stay open but I have no idea how to do this nor can I seem to find a suitable solution.

This is my code

```
<script>
    import TestPagefrom './TestPage.vue';
    import * as params from './../params';

    export default {
        name: 'TestPage',

        components: {
            appTestPage: TestPage
        },

        data() {
            return {
                osSelectAllLabel: 'Select all',
                osCheckboxes: [
                    { id: "awaitingDespatch", name: "Awaiting - Despatch" }, 
                    { id: "awaitingStock", name: "Awaiting - Stock" }, 
                    { id: "cancelledPostOrder", name: "Cancelled - Post-order" }, 
                    { id: "cancelledPreOrder", name: "Cancelled - Pre-order" }, 
                    { id: "completed", name: "Completed" },
                    { id: "created", name: "Created" },
                    { id: "fullyInvoiced", name: "Fully invoiced" },
                    { id: "orderError", name: "Order error" },
                    { id: "ShippedMoreThanOne", name: "Shipped - More than one delivery" },
                    { id: "ShippedPart", name: "Shipped - Part" }
                ],
                osSelected: [],

                loading: true,
            }
        },

        computed: {
            vat() {
                return params.VAT * 100;
            },

            productOrders() {
                return this.$store.getters.orderPaginator.items;
            },

            osSelectAll: {
                get: function () {
                    return this.osCheckboxes ? this.osSelected.length == this.osCheckboxes.length : false;
                },

                set: function (osValue) {
                    var osSelected = [];
                    var osSelectAllLabel = 'Select all';

                    if (osValue) {
                        var osSelectAllLabel = 'Unselect all';
                        this.osSelectAllLabel = osSelectAllLabel;

                        this.osCheckboxes.forEach(function (osCheckbox) {
                            osSelected.push(osCheckbox.id);
                        });
                    }

                    this.osSelected = osSelected;
                    this.osSelectAllLabel = osSelectAllLabel;
                }
            }
        },

        created() {
            this.osSelectAll = true;

            // Fetch orders with basic filter
            this.searchProductOrders({});
        },

        mounted() {
            // Required for when page already previously loaded
            if (this.$store.getters.orderPaginator.items.length > 0) {
                this.loading = false;
                this.$refs.searchField.focus();
            }
        },

        methods: {
            searchProductOrders(filters) {
                axios.post('/product-orders/search', filters)
                    .then((response) => {
                        this.loading = false;
                        this.$refs.searchField.focus();

                        let paginator = response.data.paginator;

                        this.$store.dispatch('paginateOrders', paginator);
                        this.$store.dispatch('setOrderPaginator', paginator);
                    })
                    .catch((error) => { });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately the code you posted does not show the logic by which you control the visibility of your dropdown list! How do you handle this?

Comment: @MarcRo - Its standard `Bootstrap 4`, click the `btn-group` button and it displays the `Div` with my `checkboxes` in

Comment: Then it is a bootstrap issue and doesn't really have anything to do with vue!

Comment: @MarcRo - Its working as designed by `Boostrap` my issue is i need to keep the `class` 'show' when i click on a `checkbox` within the `btn-group` so isn't a `Bootstrap` issue i just need to know how and the best to apply re-apply the 'show' when clicked on but if clicking anywhere else on the page then it should be `hidden`

Comment: When you just reapply the class you might have style flickering. It is clearly not designed to be used in this way. You might be able to change bootstraps behavior, though.